# how to create sliding divs inside another sliding div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dhtml

i want to slide a div inside another div as shown [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cGZxv/61/)
but my divs are float type. how can i reproduce the same effect [fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/anuran/8dM7z/2/) with the white box with "apple" text to slide inside the black div containind it.
my javascript code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#container').mousemove(function (e) {
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        $("#recent").text(x + " , " + e.pageX + " , " + $("mainslide").left);
        if (e.pageX <= $(window).width() / 2) 
            $('#slider').css({'left': $(window).width() - e.pageX });
        else 
            $('#slider').css({'right': $(window).width() - e.pageX });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the `left` & `right` CSS properties you have to set the `position` property to anything but `static`. Only `position:static` & `position:relative` work with the `float` property.

So you should add: `#slider { position:relative }` to your CSS and remove other `position` CSS properties from `#slider`

Comment: position is already set to relative for #slider, u can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anuran/8dM7z/2/)

Comment: why don't you use `position absolute`?

Comment: i tried it but its still not working , i want to slide the #slider inside #mainslide in opposite direction of mouse coordinates
like [here]:(http://www.adhamdannaway.com/)